# Difference between a storyboard and a storyboard package?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

When I go to move a view controller into it's own storyboard file I go to Xcode > Editor > Refactor to Storyboard. Here, a pop-up window shows for naming the new storyboard file and some various settings. One of these settings is **Format** with 2 options:

**Interface Builder Storyboard** or 
**Interface Builder Storyboard Package**

(see screenshot)

What is an Interface Builder Storyboard Package and how is it different than an Interface Builder Storyboard?

[image: Interface builder storyboard package]

Answer (score 0):

> What is an Interface Builder Storyboard Package and how is it different than an Interface Builder Storyboard?

I'd never noticed the Storyboard Package option, so I tried out both. With the Storyboard option, you get what you'd expect: a single IB storyboard file. With the Storyboard Package option, you get a MacOS package, i.e. a directory that looks like a single file in the Finder, but actually contains several files. You can inspect the contents by right-clicking on the package and choosing "Show Package Contents" from the context menu. In my case, I got the following:

[image: Storyboard package contents]

I happened to be working with a MacOS project rather than an iOS project, which is why there's a `MainMenu.nib` file there. The `designable.storyboard` appears to be the same size as the storyboard file I got with the plain old Storyboard option. I'm not sure what storyboard packages are useful for, but in general packages let you include various resources all in a single entity that looks like a file to the user, so perhaps they're needed for some sorts of extensions?